# Dependecy property ICommand doesn't work in nested control

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I have a UserControl with DependecyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "OpenCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(BaseRouteFlatView),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

 public ICommand OpenCommand
 {
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(OpenCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OpenCommandProperty, value); }
 }
```

In Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="myUserControl">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="first" Command="{Binding OpenCommand, ElementName=myUserControl}"/> <!--Command works-->
        <controls:DropDownButtonControl>
            <controls:DropDownButtonControl.DropDownContent>
                <Button x:Name="second" Command="{Binding OpenCommand, ElementName=myUserControl}"/>  <!--Command doesn't work-->
            </controls:DropDownButtonControl.DropDownContent>
        </controls:DropDownButtonControl>
    </StackPanel>
</abstractions:UserControlBase>
```

What source I have to specify for working command in second button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785228/c-wpf-binding-to-an-element-outside-of-the-visual-logical-tree.

Comment: I have seen this topic. But it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public UserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NameScope.SetNameScope(second, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
}
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to use relative source instead of dependecy property? Like this 

<Button x:Name="second" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:ParentView}}, Path= DataContext.OpenCommand}}"/>

In DropDownButtonControl this construction doesn't work